# How to disable PDB file creation in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, pdb-files

**IDE:** I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (Language: C#, .NET 4.5).

**Issue:** When I compile a release solution a PDB file is generated.

**Question:** How to disable PDB file creation in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In the main menu navigate to **Project**, and at the bottom ***Project Name* Properties**.
2. In the left pane, click on **Build**, then you should see:

[image: Project Properties -> Build]

3. Now, click on **Advanced** button at the bottom-right corner.
4. Finally, you can chose **None** in **Debug info**.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a C/C++ project?

Comment: @stackoverflowwww No, I have tried and tested only a C# solution.

Comment: This successfully controls whether Build puts a .pdb for my .exe, but the various .dll are still receiving their .pdb files. Is there a way to disable .pdb being created for any of the library .dll when using Build?

Comment: @cusman Hello. I completely transitioned to Linux many years ago. Do not have access to Visual Studio to check this out. Asking search engine might help more. Cheers.