# How to disable PDB file creation for C/C++ in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols, pdb-files

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784553/how-to-disable-pdb-file-creation-in-visual-studio-2015) SO question / answer is just for C#.

I tried several options, but none of them worked. Among others, I tried:

- Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info -> No
- Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File -> No
- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format -> None
- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Program Database File Name ->
- Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options -> /DEBUG:NONE

How can I stop Visual Studio creating a PDB file (and thus adding a link to it in the executable) for my C/C++ projects?

Comment: why? if the tool crashes you can't debug it.

Comment: I don‘t want the full path to the PDB inside my binary. I also don’t want any debug info in my binaries, for IP protection.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't build in Release mode?

Comment: I can build in release mode. But this also generates a PDB file.

Comment: the path is not embedded in exe. The linker adds a GUID in the exe + PDB and this Guid is used to find the correct PDB. An the PDB includes the source information if it is a private PDB

Comment: I am pretty sure the path to the PDB is embedded. I can extract it.

Comment: See [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109189/remove-pdb-references-from-released-file)